# Image Crashes the Application

Tags: java, android, image

I'm using navigation fragment template in the Android Studio. I have added an ImageView in the fragment_main.xml as follows

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/at"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />
```

And the java code is as follows
In OnCreate Method.

```
img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

In Section attached method.

```
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.at);
```

Every time i run this code it crashes. If the image source is set in XML it works awesomely well, but when i use java file to change image source. It crashes saying the Unfortunately Application has stopped.
Image Details if Necessary
Image Size:32.3 kb
Dimensions: 450*432 pixels

Comment: Great, but you should provide some code, the stacktrace or some context so we can understand what is happening. Btw, you are asking your question as it is a Quote, which is not, so format it properly.

Comment: Also, you should provide the error codes if there are any

Comment: You should post the exact error you are getting.  More than likely either you don't have a reference to the item you are trying to change, or you are accessing it too early where it still hasn't been inflated

Comment: I'm posting the whole source

Comment: why are you setting the resource by code when it's already set in your xml layout?

Comment: Missing the error message, a stack-trace and something reproducible.

Comment: no error message. Just the message, "Unfortunately the app has stopped"

Comment: I needed to change it dynamically later. Rt nw i have kept only one image in drawable @TheWhiteLlama

Comment: I will post my logcat as soon as i am on my windows

Answer (score 0):

See android Console Log,if can find source of error there

Is the crash reports coming from some version of android, and you have certain resources only in qualified folders, i.e. "drawable-mdpi" instead of just "drawable"? read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

if you are using Eclipse, have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project? That fixed a similar problem I was having.

Comment: i'm using android studio. And the image is in drawable folder

Comment: android Console Log is your best friend,logcat will give you log error that is how i find my error